# Is it possible to generate pie chart with SEDE built-in graph tool?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Sometime I would like to explore data in pie chart, for instance, top 10 users posts proportion.

for that case line graph (https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206772/desc#graph) does not make sense.

Comment: If you don't like lines, you can try dots: https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1207410/desc#graph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SEDE only supports one graph type, and that is a line graph.

If you want anything fancier you need to resort to off-site tooling. One option is to export the resultset to a CSV (click the download CSV link at the top right of result grid)  and then use your favorite Excel program to import the CSV and produce a chart there.

Alternatively you can output the resultset as JSON and then feed it into one of the graphical javascript libraries that exist, for example [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

Here is an example of a [query that produces JSON](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1207481?opt.textResults=true).

Its output goes copy-paste after the `var data =` in the below snippet and then you have to use the API from D3 to get anything on the screen.

The below example is based off [this tutorial](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/pie_annotation.html) by [Yan Holtz](https://www.yan-holtz.com/)

```js
// pasted from SEDE
// do not forget to adjust the dataValue 
// and labelValue functions with the actual
// attribute names you have here;
var data = [{"post_count":4200,"OwnerUserId":10264},{"post_count":3325,"OwnerUserId":32},{"post_count":2730,"OwnerUserId":42184},{"post_count":2674,"OwnerUserId":26439},{"post_count":2326,"OwnerUserId":24231},{"post_count":2228,"OwnerUserId":3187},{"post_count":2155,"OwnerUserId":113},{"post_count":1592,"OwnerUserId":5144},{"post_count":1360,"OwnerUserId":30978},{"post_count":1351,"OwnerUserId":803}] 


function dataValue(record) {
  // post_count is the value
  return record.value.post_count;
}

function labelValue(record) {
  // this makes the label
  // form OwnerUserId and Post_count
  return record.data.value.OwnerUserId 
       + ' (' 
       + record.data.value.post_count 
       + ')'; 
}

var pie = d3.pie().value(dataValue);

var dataBuilder = pie(d3.entries(data))

var svg = d3
  .select("#viz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(250,250)");

var arcBuilder = d3.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(200);
var arcTextBuilder = d3.arc().innerRadius(190).outerRadius(200);

svg.selectAll('foo')
   .data(dataBuilder)
   .enter()
   .append('path')
     .attr('d', arcBuilder)
     .attr("stroke", "black")
     .style("stroke-width", "2px")
     .style("opacity", 0.5);
 
 svg.selectAll('foo')
   .data(dataBuilder)
   .enter()
   .append('text')
     .text(labelValue)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcTextBuilder.centroid(d) + ")";  })
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .style("font-size", 14)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>
```